# Why do delegating method for file access in LD_PRELOAD override cause permission errors?

Tags: permissions, configure, ld-preload

I'm working on a successor of `auto-apt`, a script which records `open`, `access` and `stat` requests for files (e.g. during run of `configure` scripts) and compares them with a list of installed files and files available in `Contents.gz` indices. This recoding has been done in the original which is undocumented and unmaintained for years (and the author unreachable) with a shared library used in `LD_PRELOAD` overriding `open`, `access`, `stat`, `open64`, `stat64`, etc.

I'm started learning how to use `LD_PRELOAD` with https://rafalcieslak.wordpress.com/2013/04/02/dynamic-linker-tricks-using-ld_preload-to-cheat-inject-features-and-investigate-programs/. I do not understand the original.

While for some programs, like `gnome-calculator`, there're no issues, I'm experiencing `permission denied` errors at the beginning of `configure` of GCC 7.2 and bison 3.0.4, e.g.

```
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether ln works... yes
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for gawk... gawk
checking for libatomic support... yes
checking for libcilkrts support... yes
checking for libitm support... yes
checking for libsanitizer support... yes
checking for libvtv support... yes
checking for libmpx support... yes
checking for libhsail-rt support... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
./configure: line 4297: conftest.err: Permission denied
./configure: line 4297: conftest.err: Permission denied
./configure: line 4297: conftest.err: Permission denied
cat: confdefs.h: Permission denied
checking for C compiler default output file name... 
sed: can't read conftest.c: Permission denied
configure: error: in `/home/richter/sources/gcc-7.2.0':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.
cat: confdefs.h: Permission denied
```

(I'm aware that one has to download prerequisistes with a script in `contrib`, but that shouldn't influce the issue here and GCC seems a good example for reproduction).

Following the referenced blog post I created

```
/*
 * Experiments with LD_PRELOAD following
 * https://web.archive.org/web/20171226024326/https://rafalcieslak.wordpress.com/2013/04/02/dynamic-linker-tricks-using-ld_preload-to-cheat-inject-features-and-investigate-programs/
 */

#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef int (*orig_open_f_type)(const char *filename, int flags);
typedef int (*orig_stat_f_type)(int ver, const char *filename, struct stat *buf);
typedef int (*orig_stat64_f_type)(int ver, const char *filename, struct stat64 *buf);

int open(const char *filename, int flags, ...)
{
    orig_open_f_type orig_open;
    orig_open = (orig_open_f_type)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT,"open");
    return orig_open(filename, flags);
}

int __libc_open(const char *filename, int flags, ...)
{
    orig_open_f_type orig_open;
    orig_open = (orig_open_f_type)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT,"__libc_open");
    return orig_open(filename, flags);
}

int open64(const char *filename, int flags, ...)
{
    orig_open_f_type orig_open;
    orig_open = (orig_open_f_type)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT,"open64");
    return orig_open(filename, flags);
}

int __libc_open64(const char *filename, int flags, ...)
{
    orig_open_f_type orig_open;
    orig_open = (orig_open_f_type)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT,"__libc_open64");
    return orig_open(filename, flags);
}

int access(const char *filename, int type)
{
    orig_open_f_type orig_open;
    orig_open = (orig_open_f_type)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT,"access");
    return orig_open(filename, type);
}

int euidaccess(const char *filename, int type)
{
    orig_open_f_type orig_open;
    orig_open = (orig_open_f_type)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT,"euidaccess");
    return orig_open(filename, type);
}

int __xstat(int ver, const char *filename, struct stat *buf)
{
    orig_stat_f_type orig_stat;
    orig_stat = (orig_stat_f_type)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT,"__xstat");
    return orig_stat(ver, filename, buf);
}

int __xstat64(int ver, const char *filename, struct stat64 *buf)
{
    orig_stat64_f_type orig_stat64;
    orig_stat64 = (orig_stat64_f_type)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT,"__xstat64");
    return orig_stat64(ver, filename, buf);
}

int __lxstat(int ver, const char *filename, struct stat *buf)
{
    orig_stat_f_type orig_stat;
    orig_stat = (orig_stat_f_type)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT,"__lxstat");
    return orig_stat(ver, filename, buf);
}

int __lxstat64(int ver, const char *filename, struct stat64 *buf)
{
    orig_stat64_f_type orig_stat64;
    orig_stat64 = (orig_stat64_f_type)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT,"__lxstat64");
    return orig_stat64(ver, filename, buf);
}
```

which creates the above output when running `env LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/ldpreload.so dash ./configure`. `config.log` doesn't seem to help:

```
configure:3309: checking for libhsail-rt support
configure:3321: result: yes
configure:4038: checking for gcc
configure:4054: found /usr/bin/gcc
configure:4065: result: gcc
configure:4294: checking for C compiler version
configure:4303: gcc --version >&5
gcc (Ubuntu 7.2.0-8ubuntu3) 7.2.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:4314: $? = 0
configure:4303: gcc -v >&5
configure:4314: $? = 1
configure:4303: gcc -V >&5
configure:4314: $? = 1
configure:4303: gcc -qversion >&5
configure:4314: $? = 1
configure:4334: checking for C compiler default output file name
configure:4356: gcc    conftest.c  >&5
cc1: fatal error: conftest.c: Permission denied
compilation terminated.
configure:4360: $? = 1
configure:4397: result: 
configure: failed program was:
configure:4403: error: in `/home/richter/sources/gcc-7.2.0':
configure:4407: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.
```

A MCVE can be found at https://gitlab.com/krichter/ld-preload-demo.

Comment: It looks quite suspicious for me, that you don't pass the last argument `mode` of `open`, etc. to the original function. I suggest you to trace the syscalls of your programs (initially maybe not entire `configure` but something simpler) with `strace` (use `-E` to pass `LD_PRELOAD`, don't specify it for `strace` itself, use `-f` to trace child processes). I tried to prove my guess and create a minimal example, but did not succeed in it. When stracing, it shown me different nonzero `mode` on every run. Maybe it is even Undefined Behavior to not specify mode with some `flags` combination.

Comment: `man va_start` may help you with variadic arguments handling (I'm not sure, though, `open` is a regular variadic function).